# Plotting data from CSV files using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My csv file looks

```
0.0 1
0.1 2
0.2 3
0.3 4
0.5 7
1.0 9


0.0 6
0.1 10
0.2 11
0.3 12
0.5 13
1.0 14

...
```

and I want to draw the first column in x axis, second column as y axis.
So my code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt
data=genfromtxt("test",names=['x','y'])
ax=plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(data['x'],data['y'])
plt.show()
```

But this connect the end point of graph, showing straight line,
[image: graph]
<sub>(source: [tistory.com](http://cfile7.uf.tistory.com/image/24776F37554AD3670CECF8))</sub>

What I want is this graph.
[image: graph]
<sub>(source: [tistory.com](http://cfile7.uf.tistory.com/image/27372B49554AD4422EBD0F))</sub>

Then how do I read data file or are there any options in matplotlib disconnecting the line?

Comment: Show the values data['x'] and data['y']. Are they right?

Comment: If I type `print data['x'] `and `print data['y']`, it shows `[ 0.   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.5  1.   0.   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.5  1. ]` and 
`[  1.   2.   3.   4.   7.   9.   6.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.]`

Comment: No commas? What's `type(data['x'])`?

Comment: @user42298 The above output doesn't look like output from a ``repr()`` of a ``list``. Are you sure this is the output? Are you parsing the input values as floats?

Comment: [``numpy.genfromtxt()``](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Comment: @cphlewis `print type(data['x'])` says `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Oh. Your x-values aren't in order, so the plot is going back to x=0 at the 6th point. Does that explain it?

Comment: FWIW: https://gist.github.com/prologic/3100f5cac7c5be4333c3

Comment: @cphlewis yes. my data is not ordered, because my data represent the multiple lines like second picture. Then do I need to read data file for each line for graph? For example, data0 for first line, data1 for next line, data2 for next line....

Comment: Every call to `plot` will plot all the point-pairs it gets. You might be able to slice `data`, though. Look up slicing.

Comment: Actually I faced with this problem because I've used gnuplot until now, and when using gnuplot, just typing plot "test" draws no crossing lines as in the first figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, every call to plot will plot all the point-pairs it gets so you should slice the data for every column. If all the lines are of size 6 points you can do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt
data=genfromtxt("test",names=['x','y'])
x=data['x']
y=data['y']
columnsize = int(len(x)/6)
ax=plt.subplot(111)
for i in range(columnsize):
    ax.plot(x[i*6:(i+1)*6],y[i*6:(i+1)*6])
plt.show()
```

this code works when `x` and `y` are of type `numpy.ndarray`. numpy arrays support [indexing and slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) as python standard syntax.